# Why is rails setting ":null => false" on all my columns in schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Even if I never specify `:null => false` in my migrations that initially add columns to tables, rails still generates code in `schema.rb` that specifies the columns as having `:null => false`. Why is this? If I develop on my box, and then use `rake db:schema:load` on my production box, I'm going to get very different behavior!

Edit: Even if I delete `schema.rb` and run `rake db:schema:dump`, it still puts `:null => false` on the new schema even if it isn't defined like that in the actual database. It seems it can't tell whether or not a column is marked as allowing nulls. I'm using SQLite if that helps.

Comment: What version of Rails is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate that this was so subtle, but the problem was I was using the `sqlite3` gem instead of `sqlite3-ruby`. As soon as I corrected it in environment.rb, everything was better.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to ruby 1.8.7 did the trick for me.

No idea why though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which sqlite lib were you using?

Comment: Don't know if this matters to you, but I fixed htis issue, see my answer.