# Rails: differences in db/schema.rb - null: false at created_at/updated_at columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, dbmigrate

Does anybody know why whenever I run `rake db:migrate` in my production environment, the schema.rb file is changed?

The differences are only on the created_at, update_at columns of all model tables:

```
-    t.datetime "created_at"
-    t.datetime "updated_at"
+    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
+    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
```

I know that this is what it finds in the production db, but why were they created as `null: false` there and not in the development db too?

Comment: are both database's structures totally similar?

Comment: @okliv They were created with the exact same scripts (rails db migrations). Obviously the tables created on production are different on these columns but why?

Comment: Did all migrations run successfully?

Comment: @claptimes it would be fun if not and grotori hid it from us =) but...

Comment: @claptimes Yes, all migrations ran successfully.

Comment: @okliv Lol, it would be funny indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same thing on my dev machine. Running db:drop in production is not a wise idea, but what will fix the 'problem':

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

My mysql version had changed since I first created the database with rails. The migrations still ran according to the old mysql version.

This is what probabaly happens at your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql version in production system and system where you used in development mode. There was a similar issue with default values.

Check this link : https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/134121

Comment: can you paste your migration here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563297/why-is-rails-setting-null-false-on-all-my-columns-in-schema-rb?rq=1

Any use ?